# bug in java quicksort algorithm implementation

Tags: java, quicksort

somehow the last element of my input does not get sorted with the list i am feeding to the quicksort method 
for example 
 
input : 5,7,3,2,7,8,9,0,3,1,2,3 
result: 0 1 2 2 3 3 5 7 7 8 9 3

input: 5,4,2,12,9,4
result: 2 4 5 9 12 4

**any ideas where i am going wrong?**

```
public class QuickSort2 {

    private static void quickSort(int[] list) {
        quickSort(list, 0, list.length - 1);
    }

    private static void quickSort(int[] list, int p, int q) {
        if (p < q) {
            int pivotIndex = partition(list, p, q);
            quickSort(list, p, pivotIndex - 1);
            quickSort(list, pivotIndex + 1, q);
        }
    }

    private static int partition(int[] list, int p, int q) {
        int x = list[p];
        int i = p;
        int temp, temp2;
        for (int j = p + 1; j < list.length - 1; j++) {
            if (list[j] < x) {
                i = i + 1;
                // exchange list[i] with list[j]
                temp = list[i];
                list[i] = list[j];
                list[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        // exchange list[p] with list[i]
        temp2 = list[p];
        list[p] = list[i];
        list[i] = temp2;
        return i;
    }
}
```

**edit**

```
public class QuickSort2 {

    private static void quickSort(int[] list) {
        quickSort(list, 0, list.length - 1);
    }

    private static void quickSort(int[] list, int p, int q) {
        if (p < q) {
            int pivotIndex = partition(list, p, q);
            quickSort(list, p, pivotIndex - 1);
            quickSort(list, pivotIndex + 1, q);
        }
    }

    private static int partition(int[] list, int p, int q) {
        int x = list[p];
        int i = p;
        int temp, temp2;
        for (int j = p + 1; j <= q; j++) {
            if (list[j] < x) {
                i = i + 1;
                // exchange list[i] with list[j]
                temp = list[i];
                list[i] = list[j];
                list[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        // exchange list[p] with list[i]
        temp2 = list[p];
        list[p] = list[i];
        list[i] = temp2;
        return i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `for` loop "skips" the last element:

```
for (int j = p + 1; j < list.length - 1; j++)
```

Modify it like this:

```
for (int j = p + 1; j < list.length; j++)
```

Btw it should be not be `list.length` because that way you're doing unnecessary work. You're supposed to work on the `[p..q]` (both inclusive) range and not on the whole array, so this is enough:

```
for (int j = p + 1; j <= q; j++)
```

You're implementation (even though it works) looks atypical. Take a look at [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).

Comment: thank you that pretty much fixes what i was looking for